# VS 2019 Extensibility

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vs-extensibility

I've been searching the internet for the last week and can't find a working example.  I'm trying to build a visual studio extension that formats the code.  I've read up all the walk-throughs on Microsoft documentation.  I just want to know how to create a shortcut that when pressed, will read all the text in the editor and allow me to format it and write back to the editor.  I'm working with the Visual Studio 2019 SDK.

Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?  Any help here would be appreciated as I'm out of ideas where to look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a VS command, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-extension-with-a-menu-command?view=vs-2019

and then assign a shortcut to it in VS options or programmatically.

In the command, get dte.ActiveDocument and use txtDoc.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint() and other points to read and modify text, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.textdocument.startpoint?view=visualstudiosdk-2019